# Unable to assign data to specific index of array in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
let new_json = {
  sessions: []
};

new_json.sessions[0]["timing"] = []
```

Error:

```
VM73:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'timing' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:1:32
(anonymous) @ VM73:1
```

Here I am trying to add data to one index of the array

But, getting above error while doing this.

Is there any way to do this?

Please have a  look

Comment: Your sessions arrays has no value at index `0`. So `new_json.sessions[0]` will give `undefined`. This results in an error when you try and set a property of `"timing"` on `undefined`. Instead, you can set the value of index `0` to be an object literal, with the property of timing and an array value. Or, initialize your sessions array with an empty object `[{}]`

Answer (score 3):

First initialize the object at 0th position and the add the value like this

```
new_json.sessions[0] = {};
new_json.sessions[0]["timing"] = []
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by pushing the new object with `timing` property into the `sessions` array,

```js
let new_json = { sessions: [] };

new_json.sessions.push({ timing: [] })
console.log(new_json.sessions)
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

`new_json.sessions[0] = { timing: []}`

In JavaScript you can, if you want, set the value of an arbitrary index in an array.  But you cannot assign the property of an unassigned value at an arbitrary index, as your code attempts to do.  That is *accessing* the value at the index, not setting the value.